# Create join using criteria in nHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Using nHibernate criteria, I want to create a join between two entities which have a foreign key relationship but do not have entity relationship.

EmployerEntity

1. EmployerID
2. EmployerName

LocationEntity

1. LocationID
2. EmployerID
3. LocationName

SQL equivalent query is

Select EMP.EMP_Name from TBL_EMP as EMP inner join TBL_LOC as LOC on EMP.EMP_ID = LOC.EMP_ID

Answer (score 1):

It's not designed to work this way. Why are you not including the entity relationship?

If the relationship was clearly out of the question you could potentially use a cartesian product instead of a join.

### HQL

```
select emp.EmployerName
from Employer as emp, Location as loc
where emp.EmployerID = loc.EmployerID
```

HQL reference:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-from

Comment: well, that is how the relationship is defined in our application.